# How to pass MainActivity instance to BroadcastReceiver via PendingIntent(for AlarmManager)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to trigger an Alarm from MainActivity at a specific time. I also have a custom BroadcastReceiver(MyBroadcastReceiver) which catches the trigger. This scenario works fine.

I want to access the MainActivity instance in MyBroadcastReceiver. I need this so as to invoke a method that I have implemented inside MainActivity. For some reason I am not able to access the MainActivity instance. Can someone help me on this ?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent;
private Intent alarmIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int interval = 1000 * 2;

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + interval, alarmPendingIntent);
    }
}
```

MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public SniffBTBroadcastReceiver() {}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    // MY CODE WORKS TILL THIS POINT
    // HOW DO I ACCESS THE MainActivity INSTANCE HERE
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="arjunvijayakumar.sniffbt">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I was able to access the MainActivity instance through registerReceiver as it takes BroadcastReceiver as a parameter.

Is there a way to pass the MainActivity instance through Intent or PendingIntent ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to trigger an Alarm from MainActivity at a specific time.

I am assuming that your real implementation in the future will use something other than an alarm happening two seconds from now. If you really *do* just want this app to do something two seconds from now, get rid of the `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceiver` stuff, and just call `postDelayed()` on some `View` in your activity, to schedule a `Runnable` to run after 2000 milliseconds have elapsed.

> I want to access the MainActivity instance in MyBroadcastReceiver

That is not possible. There may not be a `MainActivity` instance at the time you receive the broadcast.

You are welcome to use an event bus implementation, raising an event from your `BroadcastReceiver`, then having your activity (if it exists) receive the event and do something. A well-written implementation would do something else as a fallback measure, if the activity does not exist (e.g., raise a `Notification`).

Here are implementations of this for:

- [greenrobot EventBus 2.x](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot)
- [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager)
- [Square's Otto](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/Otto)

Comment: Yes you are right. I plan to do much more than just an alarm. I am using the AlarmManager to execute an implementation every n hours. I shall look into the implementations you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @AVK: With an event period measured in hours, it is *very* unlikely that you will have an activity anymore. The user probably has moved on to other apps, and your process will be terminated sometime when you are in the background. You need to use `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler` for your timing, not a service with a `CountDownTimer`.